# Set test device programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, admob, interface-implementation

How and where do I implement the code to set my test device ID for Admob in Flutter apart from setting it in my ADMOB UI? This line "Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("myTestDeviceId"))" keeps popping

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RequestConfiguration configuration =
  RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: ["ID HERE"]);
```

And

```
MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration)
```

To your main function after mobileads.instance.initialize();

Next to the message you mentioned would be your device id ..

No need to add it in the admob setting after this

And then use actual ad units afterwards